# How to initialize a class and pass an object to the constructor in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have the following class:

```
public class MovieViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private String query;

    public MovieViewModel() {
        MyFactory factory = new MyFactory(); //Pass the query in the constructor
        //other stuff
    }
}
```

And in my `MainActivity`, I'm creating an object of this class like this:

```
MovieViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MovieViewModel.class);
```

How can I create an object of `MovieViewModel` class and in the same time I initialize the `query` String so it can be passed to the `MyFactory` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom Factory.

```
public class MovieViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private Application mApplication;
    private String mParam;


    public MovieViewModelFactory(Application application, String param) {
        mApplication = application;
        mParam = param;
    }


    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
        return (T) new MovieViewModel(mApplication, mParam);
    }
}
```

Now you can use like this

```
MovieViewModel movieViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new MovieViewModelFactory(this.getApplication(), "param")).get(MovieViewModel.class);
```

Comment: So you basically say that, in this case there is no need to extend `MovieViewModelFactory extend ViewModel`?

Comment: Did you wrong type `MovieViewModelFactory` instead of `MovieViewModel`?

Comment: `<T extends ViewModel>` is Java Generics which allows only Models extending ViewModel as return type. You will need `MovieViewModel` extend `ViewModel`.

Comment: My bad. I've created this new class but I have two errors: `MovieViewModel( ) in MovieViewModel cannot be applied to (android.app.Application, java.lang.String)` and `Unchecked cast: '***.******.myapp.MovieViewModel' to 'T'`. How can change this?

Comment: You need to make additional constructor inside `MovieViewModel` accepting Application and String.

Comment: Ok. Let me try this.

Comment: Ok, thanks! One more thing. Is this a question that a beginner, an intermediate or an expert can responde?

Comment: It is not like that, any dev (beginner or any) can answer who has read it. But the topic `ViewModel` is additional Jetpack library, so it comes in `Advanced Android`.  And I encourage developers who learn new things.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a factory class :

```
public class MovieViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private String query;

    MovieViewModel(String objectToBePassed) {
        //other stuff
    }

    static class MovieViewModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {
        private String mObject;

        public MovieViewModelFactory(String objectToBePassed) {
            mObject = objectToBePassed;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
            return (T) new MovieViewModel(mObject);
        }
    }
}
```

and usage

```
ViewModelProviders.of(context,
            new MovieViewModel.MovieViewModelFactory(object))
            .get(MovieViewModel.class);
```